# AngularJS Datepicker sets date to being 1 day earlier than chosen

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, datepicker

I'm using the datepicker from [Here](https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/)

Everything appears to work, it updates the model etc but for some reason it sets the date chosen to being 1 day earlier than the value the user clicked.

Here is my controller.

```
TodoApp.controller('DatePickCtrl', function ($scope) {
    $scope.today = function () {
        $scope.DueDate = new Date();
    };
    $scope.today();

    $scope.clear = function () {
        $scope.DueDate = null;
    };

    // Disable weekend selection
    $scope.disabled = function (date, mode) {
        return (mode === 'day' && (date.getDay() === 0 || date.getDay() === 6));
    };

    $scope.toggleMin = function () {
        $scope.minDate = $scope.minDate ? null : new Date();
    };
    $scope.toggleMin();

    $scope.open = function ($event) {
        $event.preventDefault();
        $event.stopPropagation();

        $scope.opened = true;
    };

    $scope.dateOptions = {
        formatYear: 'yy',
        startingDay: 1
    };

    $scope.formats = ['dd-MMMM-yyyy', 'yyyy/MM/dd', 'dd.MM.yyyy', 'shortDate'];
    $scope.format = $scope.formats[0];

    var tomorrow = new Date();
    tomorrow.setDate(tomorrow.getDate() + 1);
    var afterTomorrow = new Date();
    afterTomorrow.setDate(tomorrow.getDate() + 2);
    $scope.events =
      [
        {
            date: tomorrow,
            status: 'full'
        },
        {
            date: afterTomorrow,
            status: 'partially'
        }
      ];

    $scope.getDayClass = function (date, mode) {
        if (mode === 'day') {
            var dayToCheck = new Date(date).setHours(0, 0, 0, 0);

            for (var i = 0; i < $scope.events.length; i++) {
                var currentDay = new Date($scope.events[i].date).setHours(0, 0, 0, 0);

                if (dayToCheck === currentDay) {
                    return $scope.events[i].status;
                }
            }
        }

        return '';
    };
});
```

Here is my mark-up.

```
<div class="col-xs-12" ng-controller="DatePickCtrl">
        <label>Due Date</label>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <p class="input-group">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" datepicker-popup="{{format}}" ng-model="item.DueDate" is-open="opened" min-date="minDate" max-date="'2015-06-22'" datepicker-options="dateOptions" date-disabled="disabled(date, mode)" ng-required="true" close-text="Close" />
                    <span class="input-group-btn">
                        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" ng-click="open($event)"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></i></button>
                    </span>
                </p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-6">
                <label>Format:</label> <select class="form-control" ng-model="format" ng-options="f for f in formats"><option></option></select>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-info" ng-click="today()">Today</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-danger" ng-click="clear()">Clear</button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-sm btn-default" ng-click="toggleMin()" tooltip="After today restriction">Min date</button>
            </div>
        </div>
```

As you can see the only things I have changed are the removal of the inline and other pop up options as I don't need them.  And I've changed the model from dt to items.DueDate.

Any help with this would be great as I'm a little stumped at the moment.

Comment: can you provide a jsfiddle?

Comment: What is your time zone?

Answer (score 0):

OK guys I found the answer.  In the bootstrap ui angular controller there are some variables for tomorrow and afterTomorrow by commenting out that entire chunk of code the issue is resolved.

I'm unsure why these were in there but removing them has caused no errors or breaks in functionality so I'm happy to soldier on without them.

tl:dr I commented out the below code.

```
var tomorrow = new Date();
    tomorrow.setDate(tomorrow.getDate() + 1);
    var afterTomorrow = new Date();
    afterTomorrow.setDate(tomorrow.getDate() + 2);
    $scope.events =
      [
        {
            date: tomorrow,
            status: 'full'
        },
        {
            date: afterTomorrow,
            status: 'partially'
        }
      ];
```

Answer (score 0):

I have found a way. convert that date to string first.
here is the code.

```
 var SelectDate = $scope.GetFormattedDate(Date.parse($("#Date").datepicker("getDate")));            
     $scope.GetFormattedDate = function (CalDate) {
            var re = /-?\d+/;
            var WDate = CalDate.toString();
            var m = re.exec(WDate);
            var lastDate = new Date(parseInt(m[0]));
            var mm = lastDate.getMonth() + 1;
            var dd = lastDate.getDate();
            var yyyy = lastDate.getFullYear();
            var formattedDate = mm + '/' + dd + '/' + yyyy;

            return formattedDate;
        }
```

Now Pass SelectDate to your controller.
bingo problem has been resolved :)